# My Lenovo laptop doesn't support elementary OS

Tags: release-loki, lenovo

I downloaded the elementary OS distribution and tried to install that on VirtualBox, Wi-Fi doesn't work, I read the information on previous questions, but the problem hasn't solved yet. So I should to find another distribution for my laptop.

My laptop is a Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15ast (80xv00wvru).

Comment: Try the [beta](https://developer.elementary.io/) version. It has a more updated version of Ubuntu so it may work.

Comment: Not an advertisment, but I decide between Mint and ElementaryOS, I have 4 GB RAM, so what will be good for me.

Comment: It's the same one or another. Just pick your favourite

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to use wi-fi inside of virtual box, your best bet is to make a live CD/usb and try that.

Comment: Silly question, if I'll make an USB boot and try (not install) ElemntaryOS can I check the WiFi?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't mean it will work when you install elementary. It probably does however.

Comment: why do you want to use it in a virtual box? you could have it in dual boot with your actual system, and with less problems. i have a lenovo ideapad too, and eOS in dual boot with windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to plug in an external USB WiFi adaptor in order to use WiFi in virtual box BTW is your computer is already connected to internet then you don't need to connect to WiFi in virtual box in order to use internet it will be connected by default.

Anyways if you need to use the inbuilt WiFi adaptor then you should either dual boot or run live USB

Answer (score 0):

I did an install on my Lenovo 110 ideapad without any problems, though I had added an M.2 SSD drive and installed to that. I had previously installed to the internal HD without problem too.